# how does UV unwrapping work

Tags: uv

How do you get symmetrical parts to line up when unwrapping? Usually, when I try using the Smart UV project, symmetrical parts don't seem to stick together, despite the lack of seams. The location that the faces end up seems to be random.[image: Note how none of the symmetrical parts line up.]

Comment: You should unwrap manually. Manual UV unwrapping is mainly marking edges as places to “cut” the mesh surface and “unfold” it. After that, select all and unwrap, and adjust UV map as necessary. See docs.blender.org

Comment: It doesn't answer directly bur you could use a Mirror modifier and apply it when you want, the UVs will overlap and the texture will be perfectly mirrored